# Java Error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4

Tags: java, matriz

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    int n,m;

    n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el tamaño de la matriz (Filas)"));


    m = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el tamaño de la matriz (Columnas)"));



    int matriz[][];
    matriz=new int[n][m];

    for ( int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        System.out.print("\n");

        for ( int j = 0; j<m; j++){
            matriz[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("M["+ i +"]["+ j +"]=  "));
            System.out.print(matriz[i][j]);
}
```

}
/* Es un programa sencillo y como esta el codigo funciona pero y tal vez tenga un error, quisiera cambiar el j=1 i=1 y el i<=n j<=m. Y con eso me marca el error
*/

```
}
```

Comment: No comprendo el problema que tienes, el codigo asi como lo muestras no debe dar ningun error de haber sobrepasado el límite el array. Podrías darme a entender qué no te funciona?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu codigo hasta donde lo muestras funciona correctamente, el error "Java Error Exception in thread “main” java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4" hace referencia a que el ciclo se salió de sus limites, y eso pasa principalmente porque recuerda que en lenguajes de programación y en la informática en general, el conteo comienza desde 0. Teniendo eso en cuenta al querer darle "1" como valor inicial a los contadores "i" y "j" estás dejando por fuera los elementos iniciales de tu array.

```
En el caso de querer crear la siguiente matriz 2x2:

0 1
0 1

estarias dejando por fuera la primera fila (i = 0) y la primera columna (j = 0).
```

Esa es la razón por al cual te da esa excepción ya que como comienza en uno y por ejemplo n y m valen "2", del 1 al 2 solo hay una iteración, y no dos como deberia ser.

Si depronto lo que quieres es que en la entrada de datos te muestre desde el 1 podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
for(int i = 0;i < n;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j < m;j++){
            matriz[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("M["+ (i+1) +"]["+ (j+1) +"]"));
        }
    }
```

Además, una recomendación como buena práctica, utiliza un doble ciclo para crear y otro diferente para mostrar la matriz:

```
int n, m;

    n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el tamaño de la matriz (Filas)"));

    m = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el tamaño de la matriz (Columnas)"));

    int[][] matriz = new int[n][m];

    for(int i = 0;i < n;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j < m;j++){
            matriz[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("M["+ (i+1) +"]["+ (j+1) +"]"));
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0;i < n;i++){
        System.out.println();
        for(int j = 0;j < m;j++){
            System.out.print(matriz[i][j] + "\t");
        }
    }
```